# Without a toolbar, Finder opens each folder in its own window

Tags: macos, mac, finder

How do I stop Finder opening a window for each folder navigating action?

Answer (score 1):

Which OS version?

In Finder Preferences, uncheck "Always open folders in a new window" in the General page

**EDIT:** Oh, with the toolbar hidden. It might be emulating "classic" Finder behavior. Well, if you hold down Option, it will close each window as it opens the next one.

Comment: Snowie. 

Don't really want to be holding a button as I traverse my directory structure :(

Any way around that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The lozenge switches between the spatial Finder, and the browser Finder. They look and act differently. In the spatial Finder, each folder is linked to a window. Why Apple maintains this 'feature' is a mystery to me, but that's the way it is. Why do you want to use the the browser Finder without a toolbar?

Comment: And in the spatial Finder, the location of the window is remembered for each folder as well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this behavior is by design.  The problem is that without the toolbar hidden there would be no way (other than a keyboard shortcut) to go back to the previous folder.  I believe your only options are to show the toolbar or to have it keep opening new windows.

Comment: I understand its by design. In this regard, their design doesn't fit me :) - I like my keyboard.